# Video did not show up with peerJs and NextJs typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, peerjs

I'm trying to implement a visio chat with PeerJs and NextJs typescript and the video did not show up but my webcam light is on. I just tried to call the id, I do not implement yet the socket for sharing peer id. It's just a test to show video and remote video, and it does not show any error. Can anyone help me.
This is my code

```
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
/* import Peer from "peerjs"; */
import React from "react";
import { NextPage } from "next";

const Visio: NextPage = () => {
  const [peerId, setPeerId] = React.useState<string>("");
  const remoteVideoRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [remotePeerIdValue, setRemotePeerIdValue] = React.useState<string>("");
  React.useEffect(() => {
    /* import("peerjs").then(({ default: Peer }) => {
      
    }); */

    const fn = async () => {
      const Peer = (await import("peerjs")).default;
      const peer = new Peer();
      peer.on("open", (id) => {
        setPeerId(id);
      });

      peer.on("call", (call) => {
        if (window.navigator !== undefined) {
          const getUserMedia = window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia;
          getUserMedia({ video: true }, (mediaStream) => {
            call.answer(mediaStream);
          });
        } else {
          console.log("It's not work");
        }
      });
    };

    fn();
  }, []);

  const call = async (remotePeerId: string) => {
    /* import("peerjs").then(async ({ default: Peer }) => {
      
    }); */

    const Peer = (await import("peerjs")).default;
    const peer = new Peer();

    const getUserMedia = window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia;

    getUserMedia({ video: true }, (mediaStream) => {
      console.log("tonga ato ilay izy an");
      const call = peer.call(remotePeerId, mediaStream);

      call.on("stream", (remoteStream: MediaStream) => {
        console.log(remoteStream, "remote stream");
        remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = remoteStream;
        remoteVideoRef.current.onloadedmetadata = () => {
          remoteVideoRef.current.play();
        };
      });
    });
  };

  console.log(peerId, "peer ID");

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={remotePeerIdValue}
        onChange={(e) => setRemotePeerIdValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => call(remotePeerIdValue)}>Call</button>
      <div>
        <video />
      </div>
      <div>
        <video ref={remoteVideoRef} autoPlay />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Visio;
```